# Is it okay to be learning to program for iOS with an iOS 5 book?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

I'm learning some iOS development lately, but I'm learning it from an iOS 5 book, as it's well-written and well-received and I can't find many iOS 6 books out yet.

However, with iOS 6 being out, is it smart to be learning a book on iOS 5? I know iOS 4 to iOS 5 was a big jump in terms of APIs, with ARC being introduced and all. This isn't the same thing for iOS 5 - iOS 6, is it?

If I learned from an iOS 5 book would I be missing out on some really radical changes introduced in iOS 6? Or would I likely be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are less radical changes to the API, that's true. [Auto-Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853) it probably the biggest change. The rest are additions that you can check out later, like Pass Kit, Reminders API, UICollectionView or better social integration.

I wouldn't worry too much about an iOS 5 book being out-dated, if it's good. Make sure it teaches ARC and don't spend too much time learning autoresizing masks (not that it would be very complicated, but Auto-Layout is a better choice now).